crear gps en la vida real para app en flutter
he creado una app móvil en Flutter para seguimiento, ubicación y mostrar puntos en Google Maps. Actualmente, enfrento limitaciones porque la app depende de los teléfonos de los usuarios para proporcionar datos de ubicación. Esto genera problemas cuando los usuarios se quedan sin batería, no activan los servicios de ubicación o tienen dificultades para conceder permisos de ubicación.
Para solucionar esto, quiero crear un dispositivo GPS dedicado. Investigué y descubrí que podría usar Arduino con un módulo GPS (como el U-blox NEO-6M) para lograrlo, pero no estoy seguro de si se integrará sin problemas con mi app en Flutter. Además, noté que algunos dispositivos GPS prehechos podrían ofrecer APIs para desarrolladores.
¿Alguien podría orientarme sobre:
Cómo crear un dispositivo GPS con Arduino e integrarlo con una app en Flutter.
La posibilidad de usar un dispositivo GPS prehecho con una API para desarrolladores y conectarlo con Flutter?

Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.
